# How to use SimpleMembership in MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I want to use SimpleMembership in an MVC 3 website, but I'm getting the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code. Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.
```

I'm using a SQL Server database, through Entity Framework. Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="Database1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I already use EF in other parts of the application, so this connection string is correct and I have connection to the database. Can you please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. The work around I found was to  take out that "metadata=..." part of the connection string and put in just the connection string information. My look similar to this:

```
<add name="Membership" connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Database=databaseName;User ID=userId;Password=aPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: What you did is swapped Entity connection string for Sql one.